# .Net C++ Connecting two devices by IP

Tags: c++, .net, windows-phone

I've created an "Universal Windows 8" project. What I want to do is to deploy it on my PC and on my WP and connect both through the internet (by IPs).
I found the following code: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/StreamSocket-Sample-8c573931/view/SourceCode and tried to 'translate' it (in the sample the device connects only to itself - 'localhost').

Here's the code:

```
    // those are global variables used between the functions
    readString = "";
    ssocket = ref new Sockets::StreamSocket();

    Sockets::StreamSocketListener^ listener = ref new Sockets::StreamSocketListener();

#if WINAPI_FAMILY==WINAPI_FAMILY_PHONE_APP
    create_task(listener->BindEndpointAsync(ref new HostName("W.P.I.P"), "80")).then([this](task<void> previousTask)
    {
        previousTask.get();
    });
    create_task(ssocket->ConnectAsync(ref new HostName("P.C.I.P"), "80")).then([this](task<void> previousTask) ////ERROR
    {
        previousTask.get();
        DataReader^ reader = ref new DataReader(ssocket->InputStream);
        // Start a receive loop.
        ReceiveStringLoop(reader, ssocket);
    });
#else
    create_task(listener->BindEndpointAsync(ref new HostName("P.C.I.P"), "80")).then([](task<void> previous){previous.get(); });
    create_task(ssocket->ConnectAsync(ref new HostName("W.P.I.P"), "80")).then([this](void)
    {
        Platform::String^ stringToSend = "asdfasdf";
        DataWriter^ writer = ref new DataWriter(ssocket->OutputStream);
        writer->WriteUInt32(writer->MeasureString(stringToSend));
        writer->WriteString(stringToSend);
        create_task(writer->StoreAsync()).wait();
    });
#endif
```

The only difference in ReceiveStringLoop function is than instead of:

```
NotifyUserFromAsyncThread(...)
```

function, I have:

```
readString = reader->ReadString(actualStringLength);
```

---

What I do exactly is starting the app on the WP (it should start listening) after a ~second starting the app on the PC. While debugging I checked the time the

```
BindEndpointAsync()
```

function takes, it's short enough on both devices.

The error is:
"A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond."

And it occurs at

```
ConnectAsync()
```

function. (////ERROR)

---

---

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Depends on your infrastructure. It might work if both are on the same Wifi. But if Windows phone is connected to the phone operator, it is hidden behind operator's NAT and probably does not have public IP address.

Comment: Unfortunately, makes no difference whether the phone is connected to the WiFi or not, still the same exception. :(